# Fill state property after ajax request

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

I've got an issue with React.js. I want to add another property (`productGroups`) to an existing state (`this.state.mainProductGroups` - type `object array`). So I want to find out the corresponding entry in the array and add the new property to it.

This is my function:

```
getProductGroups(mainProductGroupId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        context:this,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: ({ 
            requestType: 'getProductGroups',
            countryID: this.state.countryObject.countryNo,
            languageID: Language[this.state.currentLanguage].languageNo,
            mainProductGroupID: mainProductGroupId,
        }),
        success: function (data) {
           let mainProductGroups = this.state.mainProductGroups;
           let mainPGFound = false;
           let mainPG = mainProductGroups.filter(mainProductGroup => mainProductGroup.id == mainProductGroupId);
           mainPG.productGroups = data.productGroups;
           this.setState({
              mainProductGroups: mainProductGroups,
           });
           
        }
    });
  }
```

Here is an data example of the `this.state.mainProductGroups`:

[image]

The issue is now, that the `productsGroup` property is not being filled. The ajax request returns correct values (also type `object array`). Why is it not being updated? Is there a problem, because the initial value of the property `productGroups` is `string` and now I want to overwrite this with a type of `object array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution is this one.

```
getProductGroups(mainProductGroupId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        context:this,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: ({ 
            requestType: 'getProductGroups',
            countryID: this.state.countryObject.countryNo,
            languageID: Language[this.state.currentLanguage].languageNo,
            mainProductGroupID: mainProductGroupId,
        }),
        success: (data) => {
          let mainProductGroups = this.state.mainProductGroups.map((mainProductGroup) => {
            if(mainProductGroup.id === mainProductGroupId) {
              mainProductGroup.productGroups = data.productGroups;
            }
            return mainProductGroup;
          });
          this.setState({
             mainProductGroups: mainProductGroups,
          });
        }
    });
  }
```

I think, the reason was that I did not change the state property `mainProductGroups` at all in my first solution. Now it is working fine. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change your success handler to this

```
 success: function (data) {}
```

from this

```
 success: (data)=> {}
```

See when you set state while writing `function` it is a new scope for `this` context in your callback. So it won't find `this` as `this` from the context. What you need is a lexical scoping with arrow function. Which is something you need in this case.

The problem here is

> Typically if we’re writing ES5, we’ll use something like
>   Function.prototype.bind to grab the this value from another scope to
>   change a function’s execution context. This will mainly be used in
>   callbacks inside a different scope.

see more [here](https://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/#functionality-lexical-scoping-this)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Really good to know the difference, but actually it turned out that it was a different problem. I can use it with your proposed solution, but also with the old solution (`function(data) {}`. I think, that comes due to the ajax property `context:this`. There you say jQuery, which context to use.

Answer (score 1):

Manoz is right about `this` losing context in a regular function. I would just like to take it a little further and actually extract that function into its own component method, so you'd end up with something like this:

```
updateMainProductGroups = data => {
   const { mainProductGroups } = this.state;
   const mainPG = mainProductGroups.find(mainProductGroup =>
        mainProductGroup.id === mainProductGroupId
   );
   mainPG.productGroups = data.productGroups;

   this.setState({ mainProductGroups });
}

getProductGroups(mainProductGroupId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        context: this,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: ({ 
            requestType: 'getProductGroups',
            countryID: this.state.countryObject.countryNo,
            languageID: Language[this.state.currentLanguage].languageNo,
            mainProductGroupID: mainProductGroupId,
        }),
        success: updateMainProductGroups
    });
}
```

Note: I removed this line `let mainPGFound = false;` which appears to not be used within this function, and I also changed `filter` to `find`, because you seem to be wanting to operate on a returned object, and `filter` will actually give you back an array with that object inside.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
this.setState({
    mainProductGroups: mainProductGroups,
});
```

to

```
this.setState({
   mainProductGroups: mainPG.productGroups
});
```

Comment: No, this cannot be the solution, because `mainProductGroups` contains several mainPG's. In your solution, I would overwrite it with only one mainPG.

Comment: the thing is you set your state to `mainProductGroups` which you never edit. Am i right that you want to add `data.productGroups` to your state?

Comment: But I'm using a reference of `mainProductGroups`, when I get a single object of the array. So I think, I don't need to edit the state object itself, do I?

Comment: Normally you have to

Comment: I think, in the end you were right with your hint, that I'm not editing the `mainProductGroups` state property.

Comment: then write please an answer for everyone who's running in the same error